# Unable to to set the italic property of the font class

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code written under a command button, the sheet is protected. The command button acts as a reset button and deletes data from many cells and changes font property. Here is the code:
The ranges that I am changing using this button are already added to exception

```
Range("C10:c18") = ""
Range("C20:c24") = ""
Range("c5:c6") = "_"
Range("c11:c12") = "Optional"
With Range("c11:c12")
    With .Font
         .Italic = True        '"Line 1"
         .ColorIndex = 48      '"Line 2" 
    End With
End With
```

It throws the VBA Error: Unable to to set the italic property of the font class for line 1 and

Application defined or object defined error for line 2

Comment: unprotect your sheet in code, apply formatting and protect it back. Or allow formatting cells when protecting sheet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must allow formatting cells when protecting the sheet, or protect the sheet on Workbook_Open using the UserInterfaceOnly:=True argument, so that your code can work even on protected sheets (for most things, anyway).