# "unable to set the size property of the font class" error in Excel VBA for conditional formatting, sheet is NOT protected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long VBA macro like this:

```
Private Sub ApplyCondFormRun(CellFormat As Range, ValidFormula As String, TargetRange As Range, StopIfTrue As Boolean, Strict As Boolean)
'For this to work, cell addresses in validation formula must point to the first row
'of target cell

Dim ArrFormat(1 To 9) As Variant
Dim i As Long

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'attributes to be copied to destination cells
With CellFormat
    ArrFormat(1) = .Font.Color                             'Number
    ArrFormat(2) = .Font.Size                              'Number
    ArrFormat(3) = .Font.Bold                              'Boolean
    ArrFormat(4) = .Font.Italic                            'Boolean
    ArrFormat(5) = .Font.Underline                         'No: -4142, Single: 2, Double: -4119, Single Accounting: 4, Double Accounting: 5
    If .Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then         'If cell is No fill then do nothing
        ArrFormat(6) = .Interior.ColorIndex      'Number
    Else
        ArrFormat(6) = .Interior.Color
    End If
    ArrFormat(7) = .Borders(xlLeft).Color        'Number
    ArrFormat(8) = .Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle    'Use only the left border style of the source cell & apply to whole destination cell
End With

    ArrFormat(9) = StopIfTrue                    'Boolean

TargetRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=ValidFormula 'Add new cond formating
TargetRange.FormatConditions(TargetRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With TargetRange.FormatConditions(1)
    .Font.Color = ArrFormat(1)
    .Font.Size = ArrFormat(2)
....
```

The code stops at `.Font.Size = ArrFormat(2)` line with "unable to set the size property of the font class" error. I researched many places, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537621/unable-to-to-set-the-italic-property-of-the-font-class), but my sheet is not protected at all.
[image]
FYI, the range CellFormat is the first column in the selected range in the photo above. I will apply the formats of these cells to the conditional formats of the destination cells (3rd column).

Furthermore, the line above it, `.Font.Color = ArrFormat(1)`, ran without problems.

Here is the screenshot of the error. As u can see font size is 11.
[image]
Can somebody help?

Comment: What `Range` are you passing as `CellFormat`? Are you sure `.Font.Size` is not `Null`.

Comment: @BigBen I updated above. Tks for ur comments.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You cannot set the font name or size for conditional formatting. This is not related to `VBA`, but to Excel: If you set a conditional format for a cell using the regular Excel dialog, click the "format" button and select the `Font`-Tab, you see that `Font` and `Size` properties are disabled, you cannot select anything there:

[image: Font setting dialog for conditional formatting]

Found a good explanation [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/940108-can-i-use-conditional-formatting-to-change-the-font-size-based-on-the-value-of-a-cell.html):

> Conditional Formatting cannot do what you want, because it is meant to only give the appearance format changes, not really change the properties of cells. Different fonts have different styles and spacing. The presumption is that a larger size font would force the width of the column or height of the row to be changed, which would be a change to the worksheet object environment, which Conditional Formatting cannot do. If you want the font style to change you'd need to do it yourself or employ VBA